# How do you reference overloads of a function to use as a closure?

Tags: swift, closures

Consider these functions:

```
func noArgsTest(){
    print("No args")
}

func intTest(intValue:Int){
    print("Int: \(intValue)")
}

func stringTest(stringValue:String){
    print("Int: \(stringValue)")
}
```

You can use those functions as closure arguments, or even assign them to a variable, which you can then call like so:

```
// For the 'Int' variant    
let myFunc = intTest
myFunc(4)

// For the 'String' variant    
let myFunc = stringTest
myFunc("A")

// For the parameterless variant    
let myFunc = noArgsTest
myFunc()
```

However, how do you assign a version of an overload with a specific signature? For instance, what if the functions were all named 'test', like so?

```
func test(){
    print("No args")
}

func test(value:Int){
    print("Int: \(value)")
}

func test(value:String){
    print("Int: \(value)")
}
```

How would you complete the following?

```
// For the 'Int' variant    
let myFunc = ?
myFunc(4)

// For the 'String' variant    
let myFunc = ?
myFunc("A")

// For the parameterless variant    
let myFunc = ?
myFunc()
```

I've tried the following, but none compile

```
let myFunc = test(value:)

let myFunc = test(:String)

let myFunc = test(value:String)
```

*Note: The first would work if there was only one overload with the parameter 'value' but here there are two, the Int and String versions.*

Is it possible?

Comment: In your case that would be for example `let myFunc = test as (Int) -> Void ; myFunc(4)`

Comment: So if the closure  argument was expecting a (String) -> Void, it would simply pick the correct one?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, the selection is made at the assignment `let myFunc = test as (Int) -> Void`, alternatively `let myFunc: (Int) -> Void = test`

Comment: I wasn’t clear.  Say I had a function that takes a closure argument of type `(String) -> Void`, I could simply pass `test` and the compiler would know to pass the overload that takes a String, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The compiler *somehow* needs to determine the signature from the context to pick one of the functions, that can be a type annotation, an `as` expression, or the argument type when passed to a function.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!